# Display Tooltip after a Click instead when Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tooltip

I have a Clipboard Tooltip button script that display tooltip when hover with the cursor on it.

In the [**Clipboard page**](https://clipboardjs.com/) under **Copy text from attribute** example, it display tooltip after a click to copy, while hover do nothing.

And that exactly what i want to achive. Cuz i only success display tooltip when hover.

I have tried to play with the [Clipboard page](https://clipboardjs.com) **[main.css](https://clipboardjs.com/assets/styles/main.css)** and **[primer.css](https://clipboardjs.com/bower_components/primer-css/css/primer.css)** and didnt got it to work as i want (display tooltip **after** clicking)

Also looked at the [tooltip creator documentation](http://primercss.io/tooltips/) but even there it has only hover tooltips.

Here is the **HTML** code:

```
    <div id="example-text" class="example">
    <div class="table">
       <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell">ebay</div>
          <div class="table-cell">amazon</div>
       </div>
        <div class="table-row"><p></p></div>
       <div class="table-row">
          <div class="table-cell"><button class="btn" data-clipboard-text="ebay">ebay-link</button></div>
          <div class="table-cell"><button aria-label="copied!" class="btn tooltipped tooltipped-e border p-2 mb-2 mr-2 left" data-clipboard-text="amazon">amazon-link</button></div>
       </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://clipboardjs.com/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>    
</script>    
   <script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    </script>
```

And here is the **CSS**:

```
    #example-text {width: 500px;}
    .table
{
   display:table;
    text-align: center;
}

.table-row
{
   display:table-row;
    width: 400px;
}

.table-cell
{
   display:table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    color: black;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 14px;
}


.btn[disabled] .clippy {
    opacity: .3;
}

.example {
    position: relative;
    margin: 15px 0 0;
    padding: 39px 19px 14px;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    z-index: 2;
}

.example p {
    color: #666;
}

.example:after {
    content: "copy the link";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 2px 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    color: #9da0a4;
    border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}

.example+.snippet {
    background: #f8f8f8;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    clear: both;
    top: -20px;
    padding: 20px 0 0;
}


button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0
}

button {
    overflow: visible
}

button,
select {
    text-transform: none
}

button,
html input[type="button"],
input[type="reset"],
input[type="submit"] {
    -webkit-appearance: button;
    cursor: pointer
}

button[disabled],
html input[disabled] {
    cursor: default
}

button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner {
    border: 0;
    padding: 0
}

input {
    line-height: normal
}

input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0
}

input[type="number"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="number"]::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
    height: auto
}

input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    box-sizing: content-box
}

input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration {
    -webkit-appearance: none
}


.form-control.focus,
.form-control:focus,
input[type="text"].focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="password"].focus,
input[type="password"]:focus,
input[type="email"].focus,
input[type="email"]:focus,
input[type="number"].focus,
input[type="number"]:focus,
input[type="tel"].focus,
input[type="tel"]:focus,
input[type="url"].focus,
input[type="url"]:focus,
select.focus,
select:focus,
textarea.focus,
textarea:focus {
    border-color: #51a7e8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 5px rgba(81, 167, 232, 0.5)
}

select:not([multiple]) {
    height: 34px;
    vertical-align: middle
}

input.input-contrast,
.input-contrast {
    background-color: #fafafa
}

input.input-contrast:focus,
.input-contrast:focus {
    background-color: #fff
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #aaa
}

::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #aaa
}

:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #aaa
}

::placeholder {
    color: #aaa
}

input.input-mini {
    min-height: 26px;
    padding-top: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    font-size: 12px
}

input.input-large {
    padding: 6px 10px;
    font-size: 16px
}

.input-block {
    display: block;
    width: 100%
}

.input-monospace {
    font-family: Consolas, "Liberation Mono", Menlo, Courier, monospace
}


.select {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 7px 24px 7px 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #fff url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAUCAMAAACzvE1FAAAADFBMVEUzMzMzMzMzMzMzMzMKAG/3AAAAA3RSTlMAf4C/aSLHAAAAPElEQVR42q3NMQ4AIAgEQTn//2cLdRKppSGzBYwzVXvznNWs8C58CiussPJj8h6NwgorrKRdTvuV9v16Afn0AYFOB7aYAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC) no-repeat right 8px center;
    background-size: 8px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding-right: 8px \9;
    background-image: none \9
}

.select:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color: #51a7e8;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 5px rgba(81, 167, 232, 0.5)
}

.select::-ms-expand {
    opacity: 0
}

.select-sm {
    padding-top: 3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    font-size: 12px
}

.select-sm:not([multiple]) {
    height: 26px;
    min-height: 26px
}

.clearfix:before {
    display: table;
    content: ""
}

.clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    content: ""
}


.btn {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #eee;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fcfcfc, #eee);
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none
}

.btn i {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    opacity: 0.6
}

.btn .octicon {
    vertical-align: text-top
}

.btn .counter {
    text-shadow: none;
    background-color: #e5e5e5
}

.btn:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: #51a7e8;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 167, 232, 0.5)
}

.btn:focus:hover,
.btn.selected:focus {
    border-color: #51a7e8
}

.btn:hover,
.btn:active,
.btn.zeroclipboard-is-hover,
.btn.zeroclipboard-is-active {
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ddd;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#eee, #ddd);
    border-color: #ccc
}

.btn:active,
.btn.selected,
.btn.zeroclipboard-is-active {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #b5b5b5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)
}

.btn.selected:hover {
    background-color: #cfcfcf
}

.btn:disabled,
.btn:disabled:hover,
.btn.disabled,
.btn.disabled:hover {
    color: rgba(102, 102, 102, 0.5);
    cursor: default;
    background-color: rgba(229, 229, 229, 0.5);
    background-image: none;
    border-color: rgba(197, 197, 197, 0.5);
    box-shadow: none
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #60b044;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#8add6d, #60b044);
    border-color: #5ca941
}

.btn-primary .counter {
    color: #60b044;
    background-color: #fff
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #569e3d;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#79d858, #569e3d);
    border-color: #4a993e
}

.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary.selected {
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    background-color: #569e3d;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #418737
}

.btn-primary.selected:hover {
    background-color: #4c8b36
}

.btn-primary:disabled,
.btn-primary:disabled:hover,
.btn-primary.disabled,
.btn-primary.disabled:hover {
    color: #fefefe;
    background-color: #add39f;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#c3ecb4, #add39f);
    border-color: #b9dcac #b9dcac #a7c89b
}

.btn-danger {
    color: #900
}

.btn-danger:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b33630;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#dc5f59, #b33630);
    border-color: #cd504a
}

.btn-danger:active,
.btn-danger.selected {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #b33630;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #9f312c
}

.btn-danger.selected:hover {
    background-color: #9f302b
}

.btn-danger:disabled,
.btn-danger:disabled:hover,
.btn-danger.disabled,
.btn-danger.disabled:hover {
    color: #cb7f7f;
    background-color: #efefef;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#fefefe, #efefef);
    border-color: #e1e1e1
}

.btn-danger:hover .counter,
.btn-danger:active .counter,
.btn-danger.selected .counter {
    color: #b33630;
    background-color: #fff
}

.btn-outline {
    color: #4078c0;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5
}

.btn-outline .counter {
    background-color: #eee
}

.btn-outline:hover,
.btn-outline:active,
.btn-outline.selected,
.btn-outline.zeroclipboard-is-hover,
.btn-outline.zeroclipboard-is-active {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #4078c0;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #4078c0
}

.btn-outline:hover .counter,
.btn-outline:active .counter,
.btn-outline.selected .counter,
.btn-outline.zeroclipboard-is-hover .counter,
.btn-outline.zeroclipboard-is-active .counter {
    color: #4078c0;
    background-color: #fff
}

.btn-outline.selected:hover {
    background-color: #396cad
}

.btn-outline:disabled,
.btn-outline:disabled:hover,
.btn-outline.disabled,
.btn-outline.disabled:hover {
    color: #767676;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: none;
    border-color: #e5e5e5
}

.btn-with-count {
    float: left;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0
}

.btn-sm {
    padding: 2px 10px
}


.tooltipped {
    position: relative
}

.tooltipped:after {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000000;
    display: none;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    font: normal normal 11px/1.5 Helvetica, arial, nimbussansl, liberationsans, freesans, clean, sans-serif, "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
    text-transform: none;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: pre;
    pointer-events: none;
    content: attr(aria-label);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}

.tooltipped:before {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1000001;
    display: none;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    pointer-events: none;
    content: "";
    border: 5px solid transparent
}

.tooltipped:hover:before,
.tooltipped:hover:after,
.tooltipped:active:before,
.tooltipped:active:after,
.tooltipped:focus:before,
.tooltipped:focus:after {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none
}

.tooltipped-multiline:hover:after,
.tooltipped-multiline:active:after,
.tooltipped-multiline:focus:after {
    display: table-cell
}

.tooltipped-s:after,
.tooltipped-se:after,
.tooltipped-sw:after {
    top: 100%;
    right: 50%;
    margin-top: 5px
}

.tooltipped-s:before,
.tooltipped-se:before,
.tooltipped-sw:before {
    top: auto;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.tooltipped-se:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px
}

.tooltipped-sw:after {
    margin-right: -15px
}

.tooltipped-n:after,
.tooltipped-ne:after,
.tooltipped-nw:after {
    right: 50%;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 5px
}

.tooltipped-n:before,
.tooltipped-ne:before,
.tooltipped-nw:before {
    top: -5px;
    right: 50%;
    bottom: auto;
    margin-right: -5px;
    border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.tooltipped-ne:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px
}

.tooltipped-nw:after {
    margin-right: -15px
}

.tooltipped-s:after,
.tooltipped-n:after {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(50%);
    transform: translateX(50%)
}

.tooltipped-w:after {
    right: 100%;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-right: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
    transform: translateY(50%)
}

.tooltipped-w:before {
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: -5px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.tooltipped-e:after {
    bottom: 50%;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
    transform: translateY(50%)
}

.tooltipped-e:before {
    top: 50%;
    right: -5px;
    bottom: 50%;
    margin-top: -5px;
    border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8)
}

.tooltipped-multiline:after {
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 250px;
    word-break: break-word;
    word-wrap: normal;
    white-space: pre-line;
    border-collapse: separate
}

.tooltipped-multiline.tooltipped-s:after,
.tooltipped-multiline.tooltipped-n:after {
    right: auto;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%)
}

.tooltipped-multiline.tooltipped-w:after,
.tooltipped-multiline.tooltipped-e:after {
    right: 100%
}

@media screen and (min-width: 0\0) {
    .tooltipped-multiline:after {
        width: 250px
    }
}

.tooltipped-sticky:before,
.tooltipped-sticky:after {
    display: inline-block
}

.tooltipped-sticky.tooltipped-multiline:after {
    display: table-cell
}

.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped:after {
    color: #000;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}

.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped .tooltipped-s:before,
.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped .tooltipped-se:before,
.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped .tooltipped-sw:before {
    border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}

.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped.tooltipped-n:before,
.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped.tooltipped-ne:before,
.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped.tooltipped-nw:before {
    border-top-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}

.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped.tooltipped-e:before {
    border-right-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}

.fullscreen-overlay-enabled.dark-theme .tooltipped.tooltipped-w:before {
    border-left-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8)
}
```

> **EDIT:** Getting closer:

This is the related code:

```
<div id="example-text" class="example">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-demo="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn&#39;t mean you should — clipboard.js">Copy to clipboard</button>
</div>

    <pre class="snippet">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-snippet="">
<img class="clippy" width="13" src="./index_files/clippy.svg" alt="Copy to clipboard">
</button>
<code class="html hljs xml">
<span class="hljs-comment">&lt;!-- Trigger --&gt;</span>
    <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;<span class="hljs-title">button</span> 
<span class="hljs-attribute">class</span>=<span class="hljs-value">"btn"</span> 
<span class="hljs-attribute">data-clipboard-text</span>=<span class="hljs-value">"Just because you can doesn't mean you should — clipboard.js"</span>&gt;</span>
        Copy to clipboard
    <span class="hljs-tag">&lt;/<span class="hljs-title">button</span>&gt;</span>
</code>
</pre>
```

[Tried and still without success](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/u3u1svo8/)- Wonder what exactly triger that.

How do i get tooltip **After** i click (like in the clipboardpage)?

Here's a **[live one](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/qup8272k/)**:

Comment: Because you added the tag jquery to your question: maybe you look for https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/

Comment: I have delete it. It is not jQuery from my concern.

Comment: I also have to correct me. Actually I meant the event `mouseup`. Unfortunatly I only found jquery examples for this event. Maybe `element.onmouseup = doSomething;`is the plain javascript pendant to jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. It was hiding in the **demoes.js** file.
And especially that line:

```
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-demo="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn&#39;t mean you should — clipboard.js">Copy to clipboard</button>
```

This is the corrected code:

```
<script src="https://clipboardjs.com/assets/scripts/demos.js"></script>
<div id="example-text" class="example">
<button class="btn" data-clipboard-demo="" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="Just because you can doesn&#39;t mean you should — clipboard.js">Copy to clipboard</button>
</div>

    <script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');

    clipboard.on('success', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

    clipboard.on('error', function(e) {
        console.log(e);
    });
    </script>
```

Now it is working.
Here's the result: [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/rami7250/yys3j2qe/1/)